# Criteria for the convergence of $E(g(X))$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable, and g a non-negative, strictly increasing, differentiable function. I want to show that $E(g(X)) < \infty \iff \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}g'(n)P(X>x)<\infty$.

I know that $E(g(X)) = g(0) + \int^{\infty}_{0}g'(x)P(X>x)dx$, and I got

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\inf_{x \in [n,n-1)}g'(x)P(X>n) \leq E(g(x))-g(0) \leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sup_{x \in [n,n-1)}g'(x)P(X>n-1)$

How do I proceed?

Comment: Is there any other information on the derivative? Is it monotone? Also we have no information on the behavior of $g(n+1)$ and $g(n)$ at $+\infty$

Comment: Yeah, I have been thinking along that line too, but at this point, I don't believe this statement is correct as is. It is probably more doable if g' is known to be strictly increasing.